# Duplicate class.com.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.1.5-runtime

Tags: java, android, firebase, compiler-errors, firebase-cloud-messaging

Duplicate class.com.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-20.1.5-runtime (com.google.firebase-iid:20.1.5) and jetified-firebase-messaging-23.1.1-runtime (com.Google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1)
Go to the documentation to learn how to fix dependency resolution errors.

Update fcm messaging dependencies version.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4206#issue-1409911151) workaround should help you.